# Is there any way to set a global proxy in Linux which works across all apps?

Tags: 20.04, proxy

I work at home and in the office.  While in the office I need to have a proxy set.  The problem is every app (linux, git, docker, apt, kubernetes, GNOME, all the rest) has their own way of setting proxies.  Changing all of these to proxy while in the office and to no proxy when out of the office is a real pain.  Projects like proxyman (https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan) help, but proxyman doesn't cover all apps I use.  Is there some way of setting a proxy in a single place and having all of these apps use it?  If not, why not?

[EDIT] I've edited the original question to add the requested information:

OS/Release: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (but does this really matter?...no release of Linux supports what I'm asking about to my knowledge)

Comment: This isn't a generic Linux support site (SE *Unix & Linux* provides that), so why ask here?  What OS & release are you asking about?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, please tag your version (i.e. 20.04) as specific versions of Ubuntu can have different answers. It also helps other people searching for the same problem on your version find the answer.

Comment: Also, are you open to using a VPN instead of a proxy? Although I could be wrong, it seems much easier to apply system wide using a VPN.

Comment: @mchid VPN doesn't help.  Our VPN doesn't set proxies, we have to set them by hand.

Comment: Same question on
[Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/is-there-a-way-to-set-network-proxy-system-wide)
(contains solution on tsocks, tun2socks, proxyman),
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/361690/applying-proxy-settings-system-wide-on-linux),
[AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297618/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-global-proxy-in-linux-which-works-across-all-apps).