# How to tunnel whole system traffic to a proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. How can I connect to a proxy and pass all my system's traffic through this proxy (like what a VPN does)? I have both `HTTP` and `SOCKS5` proxies available. I also tried using the proxy settings (which only lets me use proxy for the browser) or using env variables and sourcing them for terminal. But I need to have all the other apps on my device like Telegram be able to use this proxy.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the partial answer to your question:

- [How can gnome based applications such as rhythmbox use a proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186561/how-can-gnome-based-applications-such-as-rhythmbox-use-a-proxy)
- [Is there any way to set a global proxy in Linux which works across all apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297618/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-global-proxy-in-linux-which-works-across-all-apps)

Also, I think that TOR is the answer to your question. TOR is a SOCKS4/SOCKS5 encryption protocol. This means that you can use tor client and it will push all traffic through it. I am 100% sure that you can modify the tor config and change proxy servers. I did this before but I can't find my manual.

- https://parrotsec.org/docs/tools/anonsurf
- https://linuxconfig.org/install-tor-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux